# Windows 8.1 Start button not handled by Application.Current.Suspending event handler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, event-handling, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 project targeting both Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1

App resume and suspend event handlers are triggered correctly when debugging from visual studio and selecting lifecycle events. However, when I run the app natively on the Windows 8.1 device, the app suspend and resume events do not seem to be triggered. I need to clean up a MediaCapture instance upon suspending and then re-initialise it when the app resumes. Therefore it is important that these events are triggered when a user presses the start button and navigates away from the application.

Is there any reason why the app would not trigger these events outside of debugging?

Comment: Have you tried running your application in release mode?

Comment: I tried release mode and it doesn't seem to change anything. I was thinking of trying to deploy an app package and seeing if that helps.

Comment: You should read this article - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/06/17/suspend-and-resume-in-winrt.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link to that article ssakash. I found out that my app would not trigger the suspend event until a few seconds after my app was not visible. This meant that quickly pressing the start button and returning to the app would break it. This is due to using a MediaCapture instance which is required to be disposed of and then re-initialised. I used the VisibilityChanged event to detect when my app is no longer visible and then executed the necessary setup and disposal code.